# Constraint Violation While Inserting Entity

Tags: hibernate, mapping, unique-constraint

I am getting a constraint violation, as follows:

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

My java classes are:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;


@Entity    
@Table(name = "channel")
public class Channel
{
    //@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    //@GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="employee"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="channel_gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="channel_gen", strategy="increment")
    @Column(name = "channel_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty(value = "start_freq")
    @Column(name = "start_freq")
    private int startFreq;

    @JsonProperty(value = "end_freq")
    @Column(name = "end_freq")
    private int endFreq;

    @JsonProperty(value = "center")
    @Column(name = "center")
    private int center;

    @JsonProperty(value = "bandwidth")
    @Column(name = "bandwidth")
    private int bandwidth;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Report report;

    public Channel() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Report getReport() {
        return report;
    }

    public void setReport(Report report) {
        this.report = report;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getStartFreq() {
        return startFreq;
    }

    public void setStartFreq(int startFreq) {
        this.startFreq = startFreq;
    }

    public int getEndFreq() {
        return endFreq;
    }

    public void setEndFreq(int endFreq) {
        this.endFreq = endFreq;
    }

    public int getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    public void setCenter(int center) {
        this.center = center;
    }

    public int getBandwidth() {
        return bandwidth;
    }

    public void setBandwidth(int bandwidth) {
        this.bandwidth = bandwidth;
    }   
}
```

Another java class

```
import com.dgs.reports.utils.States;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity    
@Table(name = "report") 
public class Report
{
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="report_gen" , strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="report_gen")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "state")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private States state;

@JsonProperty(value = "keyspace")
@Column(name = "keyspace")
private String keyspace;

@JsonProperty(value = "quantum")
@Column(name = "quantum")
private int quantum;

@JsonProperty(value = "quantum_string")
@Column(name = "quantum_string")
private String quantumString;

@JsonProperty("report_type")
@Column(name = "report_type")
private String reportType;

@JsonProperty("start_date")
@Column(name = "start_date")
private long startDate;

@JsonProperty("end_date")
@Column(name = "end_date")
private long endDate;

@JsonProperty("channels")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "report")
private List<Channel> channels;

@JsonProperty("start_freq")
@Column(name = "start_freq")
private int startFreq;

@JsonProperty("start_freq_unit")
@Column(name = "start_freq_unit")
private String startFreqUnit;

@JsonProperty("end_freq")
@Column(name = "end_freq")
private int endFreq;

@JsonProperty("end_freq_unit")
@Column(name = "end_freq_unit")
private String endFreqUnit;

@JsonProperty("power")
@Column(name = "power")
private int power;



public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getKeyspace() {
    return keyspace;
}

public void setKeyspace(String keyspace) {
    this.keyspace = keyspace;
}

public int getQuantum() {
    return quantum;
}

public void setQuantum(int quantum) {
    this.quantum = quantum;
}

public String getQuantumString() {
    return quantumString;
}

public void setQuantumString(String quantumString) {
    this.quantumString = quantumString;
}

public String getReportType() {
    return reportType;
}

public void setReportType(String reportType) {
    this.reportType = reportType;
}

public long getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(long startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public long getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(long endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public List<Channel> getChannels() {
    return channels;
}

public void setChannels(List<Channel> channels) {
    this.channels = channels;
}

public int getStartFreq() {
    return startFreq;
}

public void setStartFreq(int startFreq) {
    this.startFreq = startFreq;
}

public String getStartFreqUnit() {
    return startFreqUnit;
}

public void setStartFreqUnit(String startFreqUnit) {
    this.startFreqUnit = startFreqUnit;
}

public int getEndFreq() {
    return endFreq;
}

public void setEndFreq(int endFreq) {
    this.endFreq = endFreq;
}

public String getEndFreqUnit() {
    return endFreqUnit;
}

public void setEndFreqUnit(String endFreqUnit) {
    this.endFreqUnit = endFreqUnit;
}

public int getPower() {
    return power;
}

public void setPower(int power) {
    this.power = power;
}

public States getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(States state) {
    this.state = state;
}
```

}

While inserting on the DB, I get this in the Catalina log file:
[image]

My table's structures are:
[image]

[image]

So the issue would be that, it seems that the auto increment feature doesnt seem to work as it's assigning always the same value to the channel entities... What I am missing ?.

Comment: Please post _code_ rather than screenshots of code.

Comment: chao Thanks ! Will do but it-s large... wait a minute

Comment: Just post the same code you have screenshots of; it should be fine. You don't have to post all your code as long as you have enough to make a workable example.

Comment: Hi again... Is that ok ?... I put the part of the code that I thought it was relevant... But it's better to put it all... Thanks for your time...

Comment: It's actually better to trim down to just the relevant bits.  (Aside from being a good debugging technique in general, it also trims down the amount of code that potential answerers have to wade through to find the problem.) I'd get rid of any members (veriables/methods) that can be taken out without causing the problem to disappear. Just test it after...if it works after you're done trimming, then you've taken out too much. :)

Comment: You should never use the increment generator anyway: it makes it impossible to have two apps (or two instances of the same app) inserting into the same table. Use an autoincrement column, and the IDENTITY strategy.